# Mongoose find in array of object within object

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Below is my mongpdb json document

```
{
        categoryId: '1',
        categoryName: 'Outdoors Equipments',
        items: [
            {
                itemId: '1',
                itemName: 'Camping Tent',
                itemDescription: 'A tent is a shelter consisting of sheets of fabric or other material draped over, attached to a frame of poles or attached to a supporting rope. While smaller tents may be free-standing or attached to the ground, large tents are usually anchored using guy ropes tied to stakes or tent pegs. First used as portable homes by nomads, tents are now more often used for recreational camping and as temporary shelters.',
                itemImage: '/images/camping-tent.jpeg',
                createdAt: DateTime.now().toLocaleString(DateTime.DATETIME_SHORT)
            },
            {
                itemId: '2',
                itemName: 'Camping Chair',
                itemDescription: 'A tent is a shelter consisting of sheets of fabric or other material draped over, attached to a frame of poles or attached to a supporting rope. While smaller tents may be free-standing or attached to the ground, large tents are usually anchored using guy ropes tied to stakes or tent pegs. First used as portable homes by nomads, tents are now more often used for recreational camping and as temporary shelters.',
                itemImage: '/images/camping-chair.jpeg',
                createdAt: DateTime.now().toLocaleString(DateTime.DATETIME_SHORT)
            },
            {
                itemId: '3',
                itemName: 'Camping Table',
                itemDescription: 'A tent is a shelter consisting of sheets of fabric or other material draped over, attached to a frame of poles or attached to a supporting rope. While smaller tents may be free-standing or attached to the ground, large tents are usually anchored using guy ropes tied to stakes or tent pegs. First used as portable homes by nomads, tents are now more often used for recreational camping and as temporary shelters.',
                itemImage: '/images/camping-table.jpeg',
                createdAt: DateTime.now().toLocaleString(DateTime.DATETIME_SHORT)
            },
        ]
    }
```

How do I search based on category and itemid and return json with category data and item data of that particular item using mongoose and nodejs express

Answer (score 0):

You can use $elemMatch and $ operator for this
[$elemMatch document](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/)  [$ operator document](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/)

here is a working example https://mongoplayground.net/p/GxWp1MIcTcB